# Connecting propositional logic and mathematical proofs

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I am a bit confused about the connection between propositional logic and mathematical proofs. The goal of a proof of the statement $(P{\implies}Q)$ is to show that it is always true, so it's a Tautology. Is this correct?

For example, I want to prove this:

> If $x$ is divisible by $6$, it is also divisble by $3$.

In propositional logic, we have

- Statement $P$: $\quad x$ is divisible by $6$
- Statement $Q$: $\quad x$ is divisible by $3$

The truth table for implications has the form

\begin{array}{cc|c@{}ccc@{}c}
P&Q&(&P&\rightarrow&Q&)\\\hline
1&1&&1&\mathbf{1}&1&\\
1&0&&1&\mathbf{0}&0&\\
0&1&&0&\mathbf{1}&1&\\
0&0&&0&\mathbf{1}&0&
\end{array}

Because the implication is always true if $P$ is false, it is sufficient to just show that $Q$ is true if $P$ is true, like in the below, right ?

- Proof:

  $x\text{ is divisible by }6\\
  \implies x= 6 \times k\\
  \implies x= (3\times 2)\times k\\
  \implies x= (2\times k)\times 3\\
  \implies x= m\times 3\\
  \implies x\text{ is divisible by }3.$

Comment: The statements `if 18 is divisible by 6, then 18 is divisble by 3` and `for each x, if x is divisible by 6 then it is also divisible by 3` may be mathematically true, but they certainly aren't tautologies. A tautology would in fact not be a useful mathematical theorem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yep, that's right. Since you showed that the claim holds assuming the antecedent ($P$) holds, then $P \implies Q$ must be true; if $P$ is false, the statement is vacuously true as you pointed out. So the implication is tautological.

In more succinct terms, $P \implies Q$ is a tautology if $P$ holds and $Q$ holds or if $P$ doesn't hold. Here, when $P$ holds (by assumption), you proved $Q$ holds. QED

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145381/discussion-on-answer-by-alborz-connecting-propositional-logic-and-mathematical-p); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your argument is correct.

I will also address your more general question about

> the connection of propositional logic and mathematical proofs

For the most part, everyday mathematics is written  in English (or other natural language) with a few symbols. So your proof is essentially

> If $6$ divides $x$ then $x = 6k = 3(2k)$ for some  integer $k$. That
> shows $x$ is also a multiple of $3$.

The formal argument with the truth table for implication is called for only if that's what your instructor requires at this stage of you education.